# Performing Stata dummy matrix expansion xi in R using model.matrix

Tags: r, stata

I'd like to turn the interaction of a continuous variable and a categorical variable into a matrix of indicator variables in R using a model matrix. In Stata, this can be done using the command

```
xi i.categorical_var*continuous_var
```

in the first case and

```
xi i.categorical_var1*i.categorical_var2
```

in the second.

I'm new to R (and SO), but I know that the `model.matrix` function serves a similar purpose. Unfortunately, after experimenting with it and looking for various examples, I can't find its application to the specific problem of turning an interaction of a continuous and categorical variable into a matrix of indicators. All I want to do is go from something like this

```
continuous <- rnorm(10)
categorical <- factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2))
```

to a matrix of dummies for the interaction of continuous and categorical to be used as a component in a matrix for `glmnet`. Among other things, I tried

```
model.matrix(~continuous*categorical1)
```

which is clearly wrong, as it produces

```
(Intercept)  continuous categorical2 categorical3 categorical4
1            1 -0.76797492             0             0             0
2            1  1.50064357             1             0             0
3            1  0.05523012             0             0             0
4            1 -1.72968823             0             0             0
5            1  0.90034781             0             1             0
6            1 -0.55831914             0             0             1
7            1 -0.93848440             0             0             0
8            1  0.41429539             1             0             0
9            1 -0.18777429             0             0             1
10           1  1.06846354             1             0             0
categorical5  continuous:categorical2       continuous:categorical3
1              0                0.0000000                0.0000000
2              0                1.5006436                0.0000000
3              0                0.0000000                0.0000000
4              0                0.0000000                0.0000000
5              0                0.0000000                0.9003478
6              0                0.0000000                0.0000000
7              1                0.0000000                0.0000000
8              0                0.4142954                0.0000000
9              0                0.0000000                0.0000000
10             0                1.0684635                0.0000000
continuous:categorical4 continuous:categorical5
1                 0.0000000                0.0000000
2                 0.0000000                0.0000000
3                 0.0000000                0.0000000
4                 0.0000000                0.0000000
5                 0.0000000                0.0000000
6                -0.5583191                0.0000000
7                 0.0000000               -0.9384844
8                 0.0000000                0.0000000
9                -0.1877743                0.0000000
10                0.0000000                0.0000000
```

Comment: What you are doing in `R` is (I think) equivalent to doing `i.categorical_var##c.continuous_var` or `i.categorical_var1##i.categorical_var2` in `Stata`.

Comment: I see. Then the problems with my code lie elsewhere. I was under the impression that there would only be ones and zeros in the final matrix. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What you are describing using `xi` is now superseded in Stata, as of Stata 11 (2009); see http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rxi.pdf  and http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew10to11 In detail, your `xi` examples are incorrect as you omitted colons. These details don't affect your question but some readers would gather incorrect impressions.

Comment: Why did you think the model matrix would have only ones and zeros?

Answer (score 0):

In R the formation of "dummy variables" is generally handled auto-magically by the formula processing code in regression or tabulation functions. The process is generally handled by `model.matrix` but the processing is usually not visible to the useR. One usually would execute something like:

```
 fit <- lm( Y ~ categ_var1*contin_var + categ_var1*categ_var2, data=dfrm)
```

There is an `interaction` function which is usually given two factor variables and which will create a vector of equal length to the longest of the input vectors. The results from using interaction( categ_var, cat_var2) in the formula above would be equivalent to what one would get with the `"*"` convention. (The "*" does not indicate just multiplication because of the factor class of the categorical variable but it appears you already knew that.)

If you omit the Intercept and continuous vectors from that model matrix you see that the continuous values are repeated in the same rows as the associated factors (noting that my `continuous` is different than yours because you didn't use `set.seed()`

```
> options( width=60)
> dfrm <- data.frame(continuous, categorical)
> model.matrix(~continuous*factor(categorical), environment=dfrm)[, c(3, 7,4,8,5,9,6,10)]
   factor(categorical)2 continuous:factor(categorical)2
1                     0                       0.0000000
2                     1                       1.3023986
3                     0                       0.0000000
4                     0                       0.0000000
5                     0                       0.0000000
6                     0                       0.0000000
7                     0                       0.0000000
8                     1                      -1.1876527
9                     0                       0.0000000
10                    1                       0.4406243
   factor(categorical)3 continuous:factor(categorical)3
1                     0                      0.00000000
2                     0                      0.00000000
3                     0                      0.00000000
4                     0                      0.00000000
5                     1                      0.09724975
6                     0                      0.00000000
7                     0                      0.00000000
8                     0                      0.00000000
9                     0                      0.00000000
10                    0                      0.00000000
   factor(categorical)4 continuous:factor(categorical)4
1                     0                       0.0000000
2                     0                       0.0000000
3                     0                       0.0000000
4                     0                       0.0000000
5                     0                       0.0000000
6                     1                      -0.4323666
7                     0                       0.0000000
8                     0                       0.0000000
9                     1                       1.0544171
10                    0                       0.0000000
   factor(categorical)5 continuous:factor(categorical)5
1                     0                        0.000000
2                     0                        0.000000
3                     0                        0.000000
4                     0                        0.000000
5                     0                        0.000000
6                     0                        0.000000
7                     1                        1.712812
8                     0                        0.000000
9                     0                        0.000000
10                    0                        0.000000
```